# Lines displayed in HTML table when display is set to none

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

This is my [image: OutputImage]

I declared style="display:none;" for td element. Element is not displayed but border is displayed. Could you please let me know what can I do to remove it.

First I tried completing the whole functionality without table tags, later added them and facing this issue.
code:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="X">Enter X >= value:</label>
      <td> <input id="X" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.05" name="X"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="r2">Enter r2 >= value:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title="Please provide r2"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>

    <td><input id="r2" title="Your Favourite Subject may be JavaScript..." type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.8" name="r2"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="choose_check_numeber">Choose number or checkbox:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title=" Please provide number or checkbox"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="choose_check_numeber" id="choose_check_numeber" placeholder="choose_check_numeber" onchange="showHide(this.value);">
        <option value="Select">select</option>
        <option value="Number">Number</option>
        <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
      </select><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="true-number" style="display:none;">

        <label for="true_value">Select number for AF count:</label>
        <a target="_blank" title="Provide number for AF count"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Link to the code:  https://codepen.io/bilvi/pen/NWYBEoG
Could you please let me know what is the best way to handle this? Do I need to handle this in the javascript?

Comment: You should include all relevant code in your post since links can be broken. I'm not seeing a `display:none;` for `td`.

Comment: It seems to be that you need to set the display: none on the TR....not the TD.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] - right now, the code seems incomplete and does not reproduce the issues displayed in the image

Comment: You set a div as display none NOT the TD.

Comment: @blurfus There is actually a MRE at the codepen link.

Comment: @E.Maggini I wouldn't call that MRE, as 98% of code in that codepen has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use tables for tabular data. Use CSS for layout

Comment: @E.Maggini it's best to include the code in the question itself - external links to codepen or fiddle can go stale (or broken) making the question incomplete and impossible to answer

Comment: Fair enough, it is an RE....not an M  :-D

Comment: Sorry for the broken link I have updated the codeThanks. @E.Maggini

Comment: I have set the display none to the TR and it seems to work, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `style` attribute up from the `<div>` to the `<tr>`.

```html
<tr style="display:none;">
  <td>
    <div id="true-number">
```

No more "lines"...

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="X">Enter X >= value:</label>
      <td> <input id="X" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.05" name="X"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="r2">Enter r2 >= value:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title="Please provide r2"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>

    <td><input id="r2" title="Your Favourite Subject may be JavaScript..." type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.8" name="r2"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="choose_check_numeber">Choose number or checkbox:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title=" Please provide number or checkbox"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="choose_check_numeber" id="choose_check_numeber" placeholder="choose_check_numeber" onchange="showHide(this.value);">
        <option value="Select">select</option>
        <option value="Number">Number</option>
        <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
      </select><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;">
    <td>
      <div id="true-number">
        <label for="true_value">Select number for AF count:</label>
        <a target="_blank" title="Provide number for AF count"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `class` to each element you want to 'hide' from the view.
then you add some CSS to set the display attribute

i.e. `<tr class="hide">`

Then in your CSS, add

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

This way, you can re-use the class for other elements (i.e. other TRs or entire tables, etc)

See demo below

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="X">Enter X >= value:</label>
      <td> <input id="X" type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.05" name="X"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="r2">Enter r2 >= value:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title="Please provide r2"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>

    <td><input id="r2" title="Your Favourite Subject may be JavaScript..." type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.8" name="r2"><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="choose_check_numeber">Choose number or checkbox:</label>
      <a target="_blank" title=" Please provide number or checkbox"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="choose_check_numeber" id="choose_check_numeber" placeholder="choose_check_numeber" onchange="showHide(this.value);">
        <option value="Select">select</option>
        <option value="Number">Number</option>
        <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
      </select><br><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hide">
    <td>
      <div id="true-number">

        <label for="true_value">Select number for AF count:</label>
        <a target="_blank" title="Provide number for AF count"><img src="https://shots.jotform.com/kade/Screenshots/blue_question_mark.png" height="13px" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```